# Firebase Analytics user properities

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have problem with Google Firebase

I use Firebase Analytics and I want to use user properities for sepatare group users on my app.
Now I´m triing

```
FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
analytics.setUserProperty("myGroup",  "1");
```

and another user

```
FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
analytics.setUserProperty("myGroup",  "2");
```

I don´t see on console Firebase Analytics. How I set user properities correctly? And than where I will see on console Firebase?

Answer (score 3):

The [Developer Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/properties#add_analytics_to_your_app_numbered) mentions that you should first register the user property in the Analytics page of the Firebase console.  You'll find a tab there entitled "User Properties".  After you register "myGroup" there, start logging more events after setting "myGroup" in your app and you will be able to filter those event reports using "myGroup" after a few hours.

Comment: Ou sorry,now I found where I have error. And Can I create multiple grapf for user properities?

Comment: Currently, you need to open two tabs in your browser to compare side-by-side but we're looking at ways to make this comparison easier for you.

Comment: Steve, if we send user_property for the posterior log_events, when we need to send other time this user_property? When our user uninstalls app and reinstall it? Or this user property was linked always for this user and we needs just send first time and after just do nothing? Sorry to asks here, greetings!

Comment: @MerlíEscarpenterPérez a user_property only needs to be set one time for a unique key throughout a session. Once done, you don't need to do it again, it is sticky. If you want to remove it, you simply set it to null or nil according to platform as suggested on the documentation. However, if the application is removed, and there is a new session of course you need to set it again. Therefore, if you enclose it within a check to see if it's set and set it only on an higher level would be the best, hence you don't call it more than required.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, as from my experience using BigQuery as well with Firebase, I want to add some more depth information about it using the comment above:

Yes, as mentioned above, to see your User Properties you need to add them like mentioned above on your Firebase Console (for filtering, etc.).

However, not adding is doesn't mean that they are not collected. It's logging regardless, they are not available on Firebase Console until you add them. However, as raw data they're there. Not necessarily an information you needed but it's good to know the truth behind it. Firebase Console doesn't let you see the raw data so you won't see it but, mentioning that it's not logging wouldn't be true.